# How do you assign the output value of one resource as input to another?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have two `.tf` files in my root module:

the first one is called `api-gateway.tf` which provision an API Gateway in AWS:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "apiGateway" {
  name          = "some_Name"
  protocol_type = "HTTP"
}

output "api_gateway_endpoint" {
value = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.apiGateway.api_endpoint}"
}
output "api_gateway_endpoint_id" {
value = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.apiGateway.id}"
}
```

I have got another `.tf` file called `route53.tf` which creates a `Route53` record :

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  zone_id = "xxxxx"
  name    = "someurl.com"
  type    = "A"
  alias {
    name                   = "${output.api_gateway_endpoint}"
    zone_id                = "${output.api_gateway_endpoint_id}"
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}
```

I need to pass the `api_endpoint` and `id` of the apigateway to route53, but I don't know how?

I have tried returning these two values using `output` and reference that inside the route53 resource, however it doesn't work. It gives me an `undeclared resource error`.

How do you assign the output value of one resource as input to another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you're processing both TF files together, there is need to use output vars, that is simply a reference.

`zone_id                = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.apiGateway.regional_zone_id}"`

---

As an example, my api gateway block (in my api_gateway.tf) is

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "devapi" 
{
  domain_name              = "${var.appLower}.${local.domain}"
  regional_certificate_arn = "${data.aws_acm_certificate.mts.arn}"

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["REGIONAL"]
  }
}
```

whereas my route53 block (in my route53.tf) looks like this

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "devapi" 
 {
  name    = "${aws_api_gateway_domain_name.devapi.domain_name}"
  type    = "A"
  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.mts.id}"

  alias {
    evaluate_target_health = true
    name                   = "${aws_api_gateway_domain_name.devapi.regional_domain_name}"
    zone_id                = "${aws_api_gateway_domain_name.devapi.regional_zone_id}"
  }
}
```